# Is there a good pattern for combining ActiveRecord results with API data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, activerecord, data-structures

What is the best way to combine two data sets from different locations?

I have one set of data from ActiveRecord which I would like to merge/combine with a data set from an API. Both data sets have a unique ID which is common between them so I would like to merge based on that ID and avoid duplicate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are unifying these data for display purposes, it's better to use a helper to arrange your data structure for any view that needs it.

Controller:

```
@model_records = ARmodel.find_my_scope
@api_records = ApiGem.gather_users
```

Helper:

```
def all_users
  ar_prop_filter = [:username, :first_name, :last_name, :current_project]
  api_prop_filter = ['ranking', 'postCount', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

  # reduce to your hashes
  model_set = @model_records.map{|rec| ar_prop_filter.inject({}){|acc, f| acc[f] = rec.send(f)} } 
  api_set = @api_records.map{|rec| api_prop_filter.inject({}){|acc, f| acc[f.to_sym] = rec[f]} }

  # add the API data to the AR data, using the AR key
  model_set.map! do |m_rec|
    api_set[m_rec[:username]].each do |k, v|
      m_rec[k] = v
    end
  end

  # add API data that is not represented in the AR data
  model_set += api_set.reject{|k, v| model_set.keys.include? k}

  return model_set
end
```

This method has inefficiencies, and assumes different data between sources, leading to gaps that you wold need to anneal or validate for your views

---

Remember to think of best-practices for MVC models - otherwise it begs the question why you would do it.

This is principally a problem because an active record object is not a simple hash. It is an instantiation of a class, and merging data into it could lead to unexpected results. If you use a library to access and API, that library may instantiate objects to – which probably will Lead to similar problems.

If you actually have a case that demands doing things just as described, then you would probably do best to represent cast each of the API and active record objects as hashes, and then `.merge` them together.  Remember that you could have key space collisions when doing this, and lose data.

Remember that when converting to hashes you will have no simple nor performant way to read save this data back to the active record or the API source.

---

Cheers

Comment: This is going to be used for a search, so I'm going to search the local db and then use the API also and display the results unified without displaying same result twice.

Comment: @AlexPanait then why wouldn't you just wrap search functionality in helper's or one of the classes static function, which returns array of some complex data structure. It would contain data from the both types based on common id. I think it makes sense to sacrifice some memory for more abstract solution